# Trying to getIntExtra() on an intent in onActivityResult(), always null when using a Chooser?

Tags: android, csv, android-intent, onactivityresult

I am wondering if using a Chooser means you can't send extra custom data to the receiving intent?

I call a file selection intent like this

```
public static void receiveFiles(final AppCompatActivity activity, int which) {
    Intent receiveIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    receiveIntent.setType("text/comma-separated-values");
    String[] mimetypes = {"text/csv", "text/comma-separated-values", "application/csv"};
    receiveIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, mimetypes);
    receiveIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    receiveIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, false);

    receiveIntent.putExtra(IMPORT_OPTION_WHICH, which); //this line
    activity.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(receiveIntent, "Pick CSV"), REQUEST_IMPORT_CSV);
}
```

But then in onActivityResult after the user selects a file:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_IMPORT_CSV:
                if (data != null) {
                    Uri uri = data.getData(); //is correct
                    int which = data.getIntExtra(IMPORT_OPTION_WHICH, -1); 
                    //but this always -1!
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

How can I get it to correctly extract the value I passed into the intent?